# No funciona mat-autocomplete de angular material

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, materialize, angular-material

Quiero crear un input de texto que tenga la función de autocompletado. La estoy implementando con angular material, pero cuando escribo en el input no se filtran las distintas opciones de autocompletado.
He importado los módulos en el archivo app.module.ts así:

```
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [       
    AppComponent,
      SelectModeComponent,
      SelectUniversityComponent,
      SelectClassComponent
   ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatInputModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Y el código en el componente es el siguiente:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input type = "text" 
         placeholder = "Class" 
         aria-label = "Class" 
         matInput 
         [matAutocomplete] = "auto"
         #autoComplInput
         >
</mat-form-field>
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" >
    <mat-option value="hola">
      Hola
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
```

Las opciones las imprimo con *ngFor pero para evitar adjuntar todo el código he utilizado una prueba con una sola opción.

Answer (score 0):

Es necesarios que el input tenga un binding del dato, con el formControl, ya que sin este no tiene la directiva de matAutocomplete de donde sacar el dato

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-swedzh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-plain-input-example.html

si te fijas en este ejemplo quedaría del siguiente modo

HTML

```
<form class="example-form">
  <input
    type="text"
    placeholder="Search for a street"
    [formControl]="control"
    [matAutocomplete]="auto"
  />
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let street of filteredStreets | async" [value]="street">
      {{street}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</form>
```

donde en el input se mapea la data desde el formControl adicional en el filteredStreets se hace el filtrado con un observable que esta en el onInit

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredStreets = this.control.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => this._filter(value))
    );
  }
```

cada que el escucha el cambio en el input filtra la data y la emite con el pipe async la recupera y la muestra